# PC with SSD VERY Slow after Power Outage

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I am on a HP Pavilion PC with a SSD drive for the main/OS drive, and runnning windows 7.

Typically a book takes < 15 seconds from power on to login to arriving at desktop.

After a power outage / several power flickers this weekend, the PC takes about 15 to 20 minutes to boot up and load windows, and arrive at the desktop.

What can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Check the RAM, make sure the correct amount is displayed on boot. Take it out and put it back in. It could be many other things, I would suggest also buying a surge protector or UPS for your computer in the future.

Comment: Should I be checking RAM in the OS? e.g. in the computer properties dialogue?

Comment: You can check there too after it has booted. It will display during start-up as well which would be faster if the machine is off.

Comment: The correct RAM amount is being recognized at startup and within windows system info.   What next :)

Comment: Is the hard drive full? You may also want to run a check disk (chkdsk) on your system.

Comment: Nope, the drive is 60% free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update:

The PC has an SSD as the OS/primary boot disk, and 3 other HDD as secondary storage.

I was focusing on the SSD as the root of the problem, but it turns out that one of the other disks was going bad, causing slowness.

So for anyone else experiencing this issue with a similar setup, I suggest powering the machine down, disconnecting power cord, and unhook all other drives besides the one with the main OS. If that solves the slowness, try connecting the additional drives one at a time.

This worked for me and it helped me identify the drive causing the issues.

Then for the bad disk, I recommend free software: RECUVA, to pull as much data off your bad drive as possible.

As for my SSD Scare, I will be purchasing an APC battery backup tonight to ensure that the PC always has a clean and steady stream of power at all times. :)